# How does Rashi elucidate on this passage?

Tags: rashi, translation, masechet-moed-katan

[Moed Katan 16b](https://www.sefaria.org/Moed_Katan.16b.22?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en) states that a righteous person can nullify the decree of God. How does Rashi explain this?

Rashi says:

> צור ישראל - מושל באדם אני מי מושל בי צדיק מושל בי ומבטלה

I have a vague idea of what Rashi is saying (making use of a dictionary). Could you kindly translate the above.

Answer (score 1):

B"H

י
צור ישראל- מושל באדם אני מי מושל בי צדיק מושל בי ומבטלה

The rock of Yisroyayl - rule over man, I {do, i.e., "I", assume referring to Hashem, rules over man}. Who rules over {literally "in"} me? A tzawdeek, {righteous person} rules over me, and nullifies it {the decree I'm assuming}

Blessings and success

Comment: tzawdeek isn't English

Comment: @robev is that a problem

Comment: Just saying tzawdeek isn't a translation

Comment: I'm guessing "tzawdeek" is a righteous person?

Comment: @ggg yes correct